# Как развернуть Teamcity на удаленном сервере?

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

Можно ли запустить сервер Teamcity не на localhost, а на удаленном сервере, чтобы доступ к Teamcity имели все разработчики, а не только находящиеся в одной локальной сети с сервером?

Answer (score 0):

чтобы все получили доступ к TeamCity необходимо, чтобы все могли "видеть" удаленный компьютер и порт, на котором крутится сервер(по умолчанию 8111).

Если у вас есть DNS сервер, то пропишите teamcity.mycompany.com с указанием IP компьютера, где крутится, либо смените имя машины на teamcity, если она в домене. Таким образом, все смогут получить доступ к тимсити через общую сеть.

Можно также и на локальном компьютере развернуть, тогда просто откройте порт 8111 и раздайте свой IP:PORT своим коллегам.